# Getting error in js which is google is not defined

Tags: javascript

Working with laravel and trying to display google map in my contact page.

but getting error theme.js:136 google is not defined.

I tried some option available on the internet but not working.

please help.

blade code:

```
 <section class="map pt-80">
        <div class="map-canvas">
            <div id="map-canvas"></div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

js:

```
/*------- Google Map --------*/
    (function () {
        var LocationData = [
            [49.2812668, -123.1035942, "26 E Hastings St, Vancouver"],
            [49.2814064, -123.1025187, "71 E Hastings St, Vancouver"],
            [49.2812336, -123.1020622, "122 E Hastings St, Vancouver"],
            [49.2813564, -123.1012253, "138 E Hastings St, Vancouver"],
            [49.2811625, -123.0985032, "242 E Hastings St, Vancouver"]
        ];

        function initialize()
        {
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'));
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

            for (var i in LocationData)
            {
                var p = LocationData[i];
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p[0], p[1]);
                bounds.extend(latlng);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latlng,
                    map: map,
                    title: p[2]
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                    infowindow.setContent(this.title);
                    infowindow.open(map, this);
                });
            }

            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }

        try {
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        } catch (e) {
            console && console.error(e.message);
        }

    }());
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkTFR.png)

Please Help.

Comment: error solve. I have not included   <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;sensor=false"></script>

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included a link to the Google JS SDK in your webpage, or if you have it was after your main application's JavaScript. You'll need to include the link to the Google JS SDK *before* your own scripts, and it shouldn't be loaded async or deferred - as your application depends on it being available.

Comment: thanks for your response. Yes I included Google JS on  my webpage and error solved